# " task.future.then " keeps throwing an error in my Flutter code

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

*This is my code -*

```
    Future uploadImage() async {
var randomno = Random(25);
final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref()
    .child('profilepics/${randomno.nextInt(5000).toString()}.jpg');
StorageUploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(selectedImage);

task.future.then((value) {
  setState(() {
    userManagement
        .updateProfilePic(value.downloadUrl.toString())
        .then((val) {
      setState(() {
        profilePicUrl = value.downloadUrl.toString();
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  });
}).catchError((e) {
  print(e);
});
  }
```

*This is the error it gives -*

The getter 'future' isn't defined for the type 'StorageUploadTask'.
Try importing the library that defines 'future', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'future'.

Although i have already imported dart:async and dart:io
Please help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StorageUploadTask` doesnt have a property called `future`, you have to use `onComplete` the following:

```
final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref()
    .child('profilepics/${randomno.nextInt(5000).toString()}.jpg');
StorageUploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(selectedImage);
task.onComplete.then((value) {
  setState(() {
    userManagement
        .updateProfilePic(value.ref.getDownloadURL().toString())
        .then((val) {
      setState(() {
        profilePicUrl = value.ref.getDownloadURL().toString();
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  });
```

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_storage/lib/src/upload_task.dart#L28

Comment: Hmm now it's giving me this error "The getter 'downloadUrl' isn't defined for the type 'StorageTaskSnapshot'.
Try importing the library that defines 'downloadUrl', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'downloadUrl'."

Comment: it should be valueref.getDownloadURL()

Comment: This is the repo - https://github.com/rajayogan/flutter-firebasestarter/blob/master/lib/profilepage.dart

Answer (score 0):

now 'onComplete' is also showing error

The getter 'onComplete' isn't defined for the type 'UploadTask'.
Try importing the library that defines 'onComplete', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'onComplete'.